# Threads issues in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have tried to implement a multithreaded crawler and it seems to be working in fetching a list or urls concurrently without any issues.
I tested each step and had the program write all html pulled to a text file. 
Now the rest of the program intends to take each html stored as a string and parse it for a list of urls from that page and then write this list to a database.
This is where the errors start:
First I have locked out the parsing process since it first caused errors by returning empty lists with the error ' property evaluation failed'
Now I have lists being returned but I cannot write this to a database.

My question is, do I need to lock out everything and why? Can I not allow all threads to parse at the same time and each write to an arraylist? Will this all hinder performance?

Here is a sample of some of my code;
first the call to go and parse a url:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(html) Then
            'get all links first

            links = parser.GetLinks(fromUrl, html)
```

then to write to a database:

```
For Each link As String In links


          recordsAffected = _
                    Links_DBObj.insert_feedurls_link(link, feedlink, execError, connObj_Generic, commObj_Generic)
```

Comment: What you you mean by "*I cannot write this to a database*"? Do you get an error message? If yes, which one and what does the line of code look like where you get the error message? And what do you mean by "lock out"?

Comment: Is one thread populating "Links" while another thread is trying to read from "Links" at the same time?  And, you're getting an error on the read portion?

Comment: Your code listings have no indication of anything threaded or locking. Please explain what these threads are doing. If each thread is doing all the code listed above, then I would guess that your DB implementation is not thread-safe. "connObj_Generic" and "commObj_Generic" are probably being shared by all the threads. That is probably your issue.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code and add `End If` and `Next` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I just had the blue screen of death and not sure if this was related to visual studio. But with regards to my question, it did not get an error message but just kept closing visual studio on its own. What I mean to ask is that should I use synclock for the database when using the arraylist 'links' as well as when parsing and assigning results to the  arraylist 'links'? I guess the threads can parse and add to the arraylist but not read from it at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I was gonna add additional code but just had my machine crash with some errors after downloading quicktime.But i apologise for not posting the right code...while my machine is restarting I can give an overview:

I used 
synclock links
  links = parser.GetLinks(fromUrl, html) 
end synclock

and then after parsing

synclock html
For Each link As String In links 
 
 
          recordsAffected = _ 
                    Links_DBObj.insert_feedurls_link(link, feedlink, execError, connObj_Generic, commObj_Generic) 
end synclock

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an ArrayList, I would use a [Synchronized Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Each reading thread can Enqueue while each writing thread can Dequeue.

Comment: Quick question, is using synclock at all effective, since I found that even when using it there is still a clash of threads trying to access it. So should I create a new queues at each function where I need file access?

Comment: Everyone should access the same queue, I'd think:
Process 1: Instantiate Queue, spin up crawlers and processors.
Process 2 - n: Crawl, acquire content, Process, Enqueue.
Process n+1: Check Queue, Dequeue, Save.